# How to get KPIs to show when KPI List is Linked to a Custom List Using Linked Data Sources in SharePoint Designer 2007?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, custom-list

So I've found multiple sources on how to linked data sources in the designer.  I get the data sources to link up by Title -> Great!  But I can't get the value of the KPI or the formatted indicator to show.  If I could at least get the value of the KPI, then I could do some conditional formatting.

Here's the setup I have a custom list with the name of the project, who owns it, ect.  For each item in that list I created a project Task List (Gantt view) based on a template I created.  Then I have one KPI list that looks at all the Project Tasks lists to see if any tasks are behind.  I'm trying to get the KPI to link with the first list of project titles.

I've tried OOB , put the Projects List as a web part on a WP page, and the KPI (as a list).  But the KPI as a list won't show the indicator or value.  If I show the KPI as a Dashboard KPI item, then I can't connect to the other list.

I tried doing with the "Destroyer" and I can't use the value or indicator in the Data View Web Part.

Is my only option to create a custom web part using Microsoft Visual Studio (because I didn't want to spend that long on this.  In fact, I've already spent too much time on it.)